# Is there a very simple way to update a page in Perl Dancer using jQuery/AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, perl, dancer

I have the following code in my main Dancer app .pm:

```
package Deadlands;
use Dancer ':syntax';
use Dice;

our $VERSION = '0.1';

get '/' => sub {
    my ($dieQty, $dieType, $bonus);
    my $button = param('button');
    $dieQty = param('dieQty');
    $dieType = param('dieType');
    $bonus = param('bonus');
    if (defined $dieQty && defined $dieType) {
        return Dice::Dice->new(dieType => $dieType, dieQty => $dieQty, bonus => $bonus)->getStandardResult();
    }
    template 'index';
};

true;
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#standardRoll').click(function() {
          $.get("/lib/Deadlands.pm", { button: '1', dieType: $("#dieType").val(), dieQty: $("#dieQty").val(), bonus: $("#bonus").val() }, processData);
          function processData(data) {
               $("#result").html(data);
          }
     });
});
```

I have a div in my web page called `result` that I want to be updated with the die roll result from Perl. Dancer keeps coming back with a 404 error in the command window when I push the submit button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/lib/Deadlands.pm` needs to be the URL of your [route](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/YANICK/Dancer-1.3119/lib/Dancer/Introduction.pod#ROUTE-HANDLERS) (probably `/` in this case), not the filesystem path of your Perl module.

Answer (score 2):

Your AJAX request needs to point to a URL that actually exists, not a filename that has nothing to do with the web. Looks like `$.get('/', ...)` would do in this case.